# Prediction error variance MA(1) process

Tags: variance, forecasting, moving-average

I was looking at the prediction error variance of an MA(1) process and we saw the following derivation for the prediction error variance.

[image]

I understand the first part of this derivation but I am wondering why we take the unconditional variance of the e-term. This e is white noise, so it has an unconditional variance equal to sigma^2, but why can we just take the unconditional variance when we are estimating the conditional variance of y_(t+1)?

Comment: I would recommend typesetting the equation rather than pasting a picture

Comment: Hi. The model is $y_t = \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ so assuming the parameters are known with certainty, then the $\epsilon_t$ is the only unknown part of the prediction so all you need is its one step ahead variance which is $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @mlofton indeed the only unkown part of the prediction is $\epsilon_t$ but I do not understand why we can use the $\sigma^2$ because that is the unconditional variance of e. The prediction error variance is using the conditional variance at time T so why can we just use the $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: For a white-noise process $\{\varepsilon_t\}$, is the conditional variance different from the unconditional variance?

Comment: @RichardHardy that is my question :))

Comment: No, they aren't different. For $\epsilon_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, ( which is the time series version of "discrete white noise" ) the one step ahead variance is the same as the unconditional variance : $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Marie: Note that, if they were different, you would still want the one step ahead variance, since it's a one step head prediction. The unconditional variance  of the model is the variance of $y_t$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ but that's not useful for a one step ahead prediction.

Comment: @mlofton thank you very much!

Comment: your welcome. note that, AFAIK, the un-conditional variance is more often used in the AR framework where $y_t$ is on both sides of the equation. This makes it's more difficult to see what the long term variance  of $y_t$ is so the unconditional variance calc is helpful.  But,  for pure MA models, the unconditional variance is more straightforward because $y_t$ is only one side of the equation.